# Laravel passport generate access token for non authenticated users

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

Basically I have an api /mobileapp/register which calls a controller to register a customer on my system. I am trying to use Laravel passport to generate an access token for the non authenticated user but I cannot understand how it will work. Basically I need to allow /mobileapp/register to be accessed securely whether using an access token or something secure. How can we achieve this?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport would be a good place to start.

Comment: @SayantanDas I have tried on both Laravel 5.3 and 5.4 . I have enabled
 'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
And also Passport::enableImplicitGrant(); in AutherServiceProvider.
But when I am hitting the url http://localhost:8888/passport/public/oauth/authorize?client_id=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback&response_type=token&scope= I am getting TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68: Any hint on this please?

Comment: then what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: tokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68 when hitting the url via postman.

Comment: is your middleware set to `'middleware' => ['auth:api']`??

Comment: Not yet . I am trying first to figure out how can i get an access token for ImplicitGrant() -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#implicit-grant-tokens. This is what my app should be calling to get an access token and my apis that are grouped under this api will need to a valid access token. Then I will start grouping my api : 'middleware' => ['auth:api']